# Add yaml parser to php.ini file

Tags: yaml, php

I want to know how to add `Yaml parser to php.ini in Ubuntu 12.04`.I had made changes in the `php.ini` files like `"extension=yaml.so"` but still its not working.So can somebody help me here?

Comment: Have you taken a look to your Apache and/or PHP error log file? It should display an error about what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes..I have.It is showing error like `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function yaml_parse_file()`

Comment: did you restart your server after modifying the php.ini file?

Comment: thanks @adrien for your quick reply..Finally it worked with me only by this `extension=yaml.so` not any quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got that.

I had to write `extension=yaml.so` without any quotes in my `php.ini` files.

Comment: This alone does not work, you also need to install the correct extensions. (see Karl's answer)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, what you have to do for PHP extension installation is something like the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-dev php-pear libyaml-dev
$ sudo pecl install yamL
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=yaml.so' >> /etc/php5/mods-available/yaml.ini"
$ sudo php5enmod yaml
```

Cheers, 
Karl at Phase3.io

**Update**

To install yaml by pecl for php7, do:

```
$ sudo pecl install yaml-2.0.0 && echo "extension=yaml.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-yaml.ini
```

Comment: You also need `sudo apt-get install php-dev`, otherwise you get `phpize not found`